# Vavr - turn List of Lists into single List

Tags: java, collections, vavr

I've got two vavr Lists:

```
List<Object> list1 = List.of("one", "two", "three", "for");
List<Object> list2 = List.of("one", "two", List.of("three", "for"));
```

How can I transform the `list2` to be equal to the `list1`?

**EDIT**

I try to explain more what I want to achive:

```
System.out.println("list1: " + list1);
System.out.println("list2: " + list2);
```

Output:

```
list1: List(one, two, three, for)
list2: List(one, two, List(three, for))
```

I want to flattening all inner lists in the `list2`, so the flattened list should be equal to `list1`:

```
System.out.println("flattened: " + flattened);
System.out.println(list1.equals(flattened));
```

Should return:

```
flattened: List(one, two, three, for)
true
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Sure, I tried `map`, `flatMap` and `transform`, but I can't make it work.

Comment: Your requirement are unclear. **You** have to first clarify how you *want* things to become equal. Is it ONLY about flattening **all** inner lists, or just the first one you find? You see: when you call `removeAll` for both lists, they are equal, too.

Comment: I want to flattening all inner lists, so the `list1.equals(list2)` should return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Vavr you don't need all the stream/collect boilerplate of the JDK:

```
List<Object> result = list2.flatMap(o -> o instanceof List ? ((List) o) : List.of(o));
```

Comment: Looks like better solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `Stream` with `flatMap`:

```
List<Object> flattened =
    list2.stream()
         .flatMap(e -> ((e instanceof List) ? ((List<Object>)e).stream() : Stream.of(e)))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(flattened);
System.out.println(list1.equals(flattened));
```

Outputs:

```
[one, two, three, four]
true
```

EDIT:

Since the OP is using a different `List`, here is a similar solution for `io.vavr.collection.List`:

```
List<Object> flattened =
    list2.toStream()
         .flatMap(e -> ((e instanceof List) ? ((List<Object>)e).toStream() : Stream.of(e)))
         .collect(List.collector());
```

Comment: Note that I use vavr, so I don't have `stream()` method on the `list2` object.

Comment: @kojot your use of `List.of` suggests you are using Java 9 or higher, so you should have Streams.

Comment: Yes I do, but the `list2` is not the `java.util.List`, it's `io.vavr.collection.List`

Comment: @kojot Maybe not really related, but why are you using vavr in the first place?

Comment: @Lino I've got Spring Webflux project. Vavr got not mutable collections, so they are thread safe.

Comment: @kojot why not use the immutable collections from the JDK? Java-9 introduced immutable collections like vavr with `List.of()`

Comment: @Eran please correct your answer to: `List<Object> flattened =
                list2.toStream()
                        .flatMap(e -> ((e instanceof List) ? ((List<Object>)e).toStream() : Stream.of(e)))
                        .collect(List.collector());` so I could mark it as correct.

Comment: @kojot are those the method names for `io.vavr.collection.List`? OK, I'll add that

Comment: @Lino With vavr I'm pretty sure that all of collections are immutable, so I can avoid side effects like `List<String> newList = Collections.unmodifiableList(oldList);
oldList.add("why this change newList too?");` There are some advantage too, like Persistent Data Structures, Validation and some useful methods.

Comment: @lino The JDK immutable collections are badly designed. Half their methods will throw a runtime exception, how is that helpful to write safe code?
Vavr collections are immutable by design, and don't suffer the JDK List API which is assumed to be mutable. Every operation returns a new list, there's no exception, and no mutation.